# Custom grid column format

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to create a formatter for a grid column field which will create select boxes, but I have already created my custom format of grid table with predefined params for table.
For data representation it creates params.columnFormats, which includes switch cases for different data types. For instance, a case for time will look like the following:

```
case "t":
    column.formatter = 'time';
    break;
```

But I have no idea how to create a case for checkbox... Any help?

Comment: Could be attached to the grid source code?

Comment: Ah, it could be, I've already solved my problem... nooby declaration of case as string, when another type declared :P

Comment: The point is that you have the solution.